# ObjectiveC+SDWebImageView : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 400.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, sdwebimage

I've gotten a secured image URL from the server as follows:

```
https://jointeffort-dev-test.s3.amazonaws.com/11316b6e-9824-418a-869e-ca4c1a453145.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJITHUU5FSWYPBZIA&Expires=1454576763&Signature=KogwFiMdpB%2B5scNI0MkDin7jTmE%3D
```

I'm trying to load image view with that url using the **SDWebImageView** i got the following error

***`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error 400.)"`***

I can able to load the images from normal imageURLs but i could n't load this kind of url which is having AccessKeyId like the above url.

Can anyone help me please.. Thanks in advance.

I have tried the following codes.. but i did nt get image on image view (URL is working fine)

**Code 1:**

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error and image url  %@, %@",error,imageURL);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"image success = %@",image);
        }
    }];
```

**Code 2:**

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
                 placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                          options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Comment: Did you set "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" for "NSAppTransportSecurity" in the Info.plist of your project?

Comment: yes I set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES

Comment: I have same problem. Have you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use **SDWebImageRetryFailed** for options when you set image.
I've also faced this issue. This error suggest that **Access is Denied** for that image.
This is because, you are not able to access the image from amazon server, OR image itself is not exists on server.
You can also inform your server team to send the exact image URL from amazon server.